# How to split a string based on position

Tags: php

I want to split a variable based on the position of characters. The resulting first string should have the previous position before specified position and the other string should contain the other portions.

Suppose if I have a variable `$var = "2013AD";`  I want

`$var1 = 2013` and `var2 = 'AD'`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: count of 4 (str_split) or between letters and numbers (regular expression)?

Comment: yes? 2 options and you answer 'yes'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uhm... Gonna go occam's razor here, but [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) ?

```
$var1 = substr($var, 0, 4);
$var2 = substr($var, 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `sscanf`

```
$var = "2013AD";
list($var1, $var2) = sscanf($var, "%4d%2s");
echo $var1, ":", $var2;
```

Output

```
2013:AD
```

And if you are working with `date` treat it as such :

```
$var = "2013AD";
$date  = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y\A\D",$var);
echo $date->format("Y");
```

Comment: This is assuming the string actually represents a date.

Comment: @bab - that's hilarious... I actually got pinged by [your comment](http://i.imgur.com/HaKzUsC.png). Not my DV btw...

Comment: @bab- hahaha... I think because I was the only other comenter and you were the OP... But still :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use the substr function

```
$var1 = substr($var, 0, 4);
$var2 = substr($var, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function py_slice($input, $slice) {
    $arg = explode(':', $slice);
    $start = intval($arg[0]);
    if ($start < 0) {
        $start += strlen($input);
    }
    if (count($arg) === 1) {
        return substr($input, $start, 1);
    }
    if (trim($arg[1]) === '') {
        return substr($input, $start);
    }
    $end = intval($arg[1]);
    if ($end < 0) {
        $end += strlen($input);
    }
    return substr($input, $start, $end - $start);
}

print py_slice('abcdefg', '2') . "\n";
print py_slice('abcdefg', '2:4') . "\n";
print py_slice('abcdefg', '2:') . "\n";
print py_slice('abcdefg', ':4') . "\n";
print py_slice('abcdefg', ':-3') . "\n";
print py_slice('abcdefg', '-3:') . "\n";

?>
```

The output from the examples:

- c
- cd
- cdefg
- abcd
- abcd
- efg

Comment: This would probably be a very useful answer on a different question. But on this post I feel it is over-kill. There isn't even an explanation that this is in fact implementing a python-like method of accessing array like objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `preg_split()` with `\K` to explode on a zero-width position in your string so that no characters are lost while splitting.  `\K` tells the regex engine to forget the previously matched one-or-more digits.  `2` acts to limit the number of elements in the output to a maximum of 2.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3rlMf))

```
$var = "2013AD";

[$year, $jesusStatus] = preg_split('~\d+\K~', $var, 2);

var_export($year);
echo "\n";
var_export($jesusStatus);
```

Output:

```
'2013'
'AD'
```