# Simple year format validation using PHP

Tags: php, validation

I would like to validate if the given year input is in a specific format or not. The format of year should be like `YYYYAD` or `YYYYBC` (eg: `2013AD`) - 4 numbers and AD/BC without any space in between.

It should return true if the input is in correct format, else false should be returned. (Some expected incorrect formats are; `123AD`, `XYZAD`, `AD2013`, `AD`, `2013`, `@123AD`, `2013ad`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is pretty similar to your last question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821635/how-to-split-a-string-based-on-position

Comment: The mentioned question is also asked by me myself. But this question has no relation with that one.

Comment: I really don't think there is a simple solution to this without using proper date functions ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regex expression such as`/^\d{4}(AD|BC)$/`.

**Explanation of regex**:

- `^` - Start of the string
- `\d{4}` - A digit from 0 to 9 repeated exactly 4 times
- `(AD|BC)` - A group of either the string "`AD`" or the string "`BC`"
- `$` - End of the string

**Code**:

```
$input = "2013BC";
if (preg_match("/^(\d{4})(AD|BC)$/", $input, $matches)) {
    echo "OK.\n";
    echo "Year: " . $matches[1] . "\n";
    echo "AC/BC: " . $matches[2];
} else {
    echo "NOT OK!";
}
```

Comment: h2ooooooo: didn't you forget a backslash in your pattern? "/\\d{4}(AD|BC)/"

Comment: @skurton Why would you use a backslash? This works perfectly fine in PHP.

Comment: is this ok for my revised question? Have a look at.

Comment: @blasteralfred What revised question? The OP hasn't changed.

Comment: @blasteralfred The code will accept any 4 digits followed by either AD or BC. Are you expecting it to fix wrong formats?

Answer (score 0):

```
function check($year)
{
  if (is_numeric(substr($year, 0, 4)) && in_array(array("AD", "BC"), substr($year, 4,6)))
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Or using REGEX, you can check against `/d{4}(AD|BC)/`

Comment: is this ok for my revised question?